# Python3: a subprocess sleeps when started by Popen

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, pipe

I need to run two commands in parallel. Each takes a long time to perform its processing (about 1 minute one and almost 2 minutes the other), and both produce many bytes on the stdout and stderr streams (about 300kB on stderr and several MB on stdout). And I have to capture both streams.

I used to use subprocess.run() to execute them, but that way I was serializing, and since the commands executed are singlethread I thought of parallelization with Popen.

Unfortunately, the simple way doesn't work:

```py
class test:
    def __init__(self, param):
        cmd = "... %d" % param  # the command line parametrized with param
        self.__p = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd), shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
    
    def waitTerm(self, t=None):
        self.__p.wait(t)
        if self.__p.returncode != 0:
            print(self.__p.stderr.read(), file=sys.stderr)
            raise Exception('failure')
        self.o = self.__p.stdout.read()

t1 = test(1)
t8 = test(8)

t1.waitTerm()  # t1 should be longer
t8.waitTerm()

# here I can use stdout from both process
print(t1.o) # this is an example
```

Processes stop in sleep. I believe this is caused by filling the buffers related to the pipes.

In this case what is the smartest thing to do?

Comment: Pipes have limited buffering, so if you don't read from the buffer it will fill up and the writer will be blocked. You can use `epoll()` to wait for data from both pipes. Looks like there are also some good ideas [here](https://lyceum-allotments.github.io/2017/03/python-and-pipes-part-6-multiple-subprocesses-and-pipes/)

Comment: How about redirecting `stdout` and `stderr` to files and then reading those after completion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Threading** and reading output as it is produced

You can use threading to start two subprocesses and then read their output as it is produced.

This helps avoid blocking the PIPEs. The `subprocess.Popen.communicate()` function can be used to capture `stdout` and `stderr`.

Here's how:

```py
import threading
import subprocess
import shlex

class Test:
    def __init__(self, param):
        cmd = "... %d" % param  # parametrized with param
        self.process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd), shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)

    def reader_thread(self):
        self.stdout, self.stderr = self.process.communicate()

    def run(self):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.reader_thread)
        thread.start()

t1 = Test(1)
t8 = Test(8)

t1.run()
t8.run()

# You may want to wait for both threads to finish here before proceeding
t1.join()
t8.join()
```